# Listas encadeadas em Java

Tags: java

supondo que eu tenha uma lista encadeada Alunos, onde deve-se registrar nome e nota, entretanto este mesmo aluno pode conter mais de uma nota. Na minha lógica, ele apenas cadastra um aluno com uma única nota, como pode-se observar no código abaixo:

**Classe responsável pelos Getters e Setters dos dados (o dado "numero" seria o identificados de cada aluno)**

```
public class Lista {

    private String nome;
    private Lista prox;
    private int numero;
    private double nota;

    public double getNota() {
        return nota;
    }

    public void setNota(double nota) {
        this.nota = nota;
    }

    public int getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(int numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public Lista getProx() {
        return prox;
    }

    public void setProx(Lista prox) {
        this.prox = prox;
    }

}
```

**Classe responsável pelos métodos de adicionar e posteriormente outras funções**

```
public class Aluno {

    Lista topo;
    Lista ultimo;
    int numero = 1;

    public String pilharAluno(String nome, double nota) {
        Lista novo = new Lista();
        novo.setNome(nome);
        novo.setNumero(this.numero);
        novo.setNota(nota);
        this.numero++;
        if (topo == null) {
            topo = novo;
            ultimo = novo;
            novo.setProx(null);
        } else {
            novo.setProx(topo);
            topo = novo;
        }
        return "Aluno cadastrado";
    }

}
```

Comment: Já tentou conectar uma lista de notas em cada aluno?

Comment: @Patrick eu pensei nesta lógica, mas não consigo implementa-lá.

Comment: Sugiro você usar C para trabalhar com estruturas de dados, pois teoricamente elas não são orientadas à objetos e sim à endereços de memória!

Comment: @DanLucioPrada, você precisa implementar a lista encadeada, é isto? Você não pode usar `LinkedList` do java? Não ficou claro para mim se você precisa apenas resolver o problema que descreveu ou que precisa, além disto, implementar a lista encadeada.

Comment: @Dherik preciso implementar uma lista encadeada para cadastro de alunos, o problema está no fato de que cada aluno pode conter mais de uma nota. (sem funções nativas do Java, tudo em forma de estruturas de dados escrita manualmente)

Comment: @DanLucioPrada você vai precisar criar uma nova classe exatamente com as mesmas funções que a classe Lista porém com atributos diferentes. Recomendo que utilize herança neste caso para não repetir código. caso este comentário não lhe ajude a entender, me responda que amanha elaboro uma resposta completa para você.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o bom senso, o aluno pode(e deve) ter X notas. Creio que seja um trabalho de estrutura de dados ou coisa do tipo, faça uma lista genérica, e depois especialize ela para o que você quer.

```
    public class Lista<T>{
        Class<T> obj;
        Lista<T> prox;
        int tamanho = 0;
        ...
        {Métodos que qualquer lista usaria: insere, retira, tamanho etc...}
        ...
    }
```

Isso é um esboço de uma lista com template em *java*, esse T é um tipo genérico que é definido em tempo de execução, a partir disso é só fazer herança para modificar o objeto lista à sua vontade.

No seu caso você teria uma lista de alunos que seria uma herança de Lista ex:

```
    public class ListaDeAlunos extends Lista<Aluno>{
        {Métodos que apenas uma lista de alunos possui(?)}
    }
```

Caso não exista métodos/funções especificas de uma lista de alunos, basta instanciar uma lista genérica para alunos

```
Lista<Aluno> alunos = new Lista<Alunos>();
```

O aluno seria um Objeto qualquer que você gostaria de "colecionar" e nele conteria uma outra herança de lista de notas(Double) que possuiria as funções/métodos específicos para uma lista de notas:

```
    public class ListaDeNotas extends Lista<Double>{
        {Métodos que apenas uma lista de notas possui: média, maior, menor...}

    }
```